# why catastrophic backtracking in this seemingly valid regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

This is my input text:

```
1. Text text
2. more text..
3. more text... 
4. more text.. 
5. more text.. 

some more text here.. 

1. This is another text.
2. This is another text contd
3. More text..
```

Now, when I use a regular expression like this to match this text:

```
1\.(.+?)\n2\.(.+?)\n3\.
```

This works fine, and matches the first 3 lines and the last 3 lines, however, when I include the other numbers in the regular expression:

```
1\.(.+?)\n2\.(.+?)\n3\.(.+?)\n4\.(.+?)\n5.(.+?)
```

It results in an immediate catastrophic backtracking error.

I am using regex101 and flags g and s.

[Test case with actual data on regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/tD1xZ0/1)

Why doesn't the regex engine ignore the second (partial) match towards the end of the file?

Comment: It may be because of the `(.+?)*` part. Can't you simply use `(.+)`?

Comment: This `(.+?)*` won't cause catastrophic backtracking because it is equivalent to `.*`. Beyond that, the other problems are: the first asterisk quantifies nothing; the non-greedy modifier in `(.+?)` is not needed, `(.+)` would do if the _dot_ does not match newlines.

Comment: What do you mean by `catastrophic backtracking` ? Did your computer explode ? Or did you get an error message ? If so what was the error ? And what was the catastophe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^1\.(.+?)\n2\.(.+?)\n3\.(.+?)\n4\.(.+?)\n5\.(.+?)$
```

This is working for me.Just remove the useless `*` from end and beginning.use `multiline` flag.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/34

Comment: I suspect the leading and trailing asterisks were meant as formatting.  If they were present in the actual regex, it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @AlanMoore the last one will compile....maybe not the first one..newaz this one works

Comment: You could have at least explained why catastrophic backtracking occurs. Without the explanation, OP will keep on using this current bad practice with lazy matching. The key is achieving linear complexity and it is possible here.

Comment: @stribizhev not very sure if the `*` is really part of match.as Alan said.He needs to clarify that

Comment: I'm just saying that advising the OP to drop those asterisks is pointless, because they aren't really present n the actual regex.  But I agree that adding anchors is probably the best solution, except you should also specify multiline mode.

Comment: The wording of the question isn't very clear, but it does say there's more text after the first five lines.  The `$` anchor won't match the end of the fifth line unless you set multiline mode.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xG0eG7/1 Here's updated version. It works on this sample, but my text is a 50 page word doc and on this one it fails with catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: @vks, if I remove the s flag, it stops with the first match

Comment: @vks https://regex101.com/r/tD1xZ0/1 . This example in this link is not throwing catastrophic backtracking yet (it was throwing on other text), but if you try to add 17 to the regex (right now its at 16), you will see how it starts to do what it is not supposed to do.

Comment: @vks it stops with the first match, if you remove s flag. The intention is to match all of the numbering sequence matches (not just the TOC)

Comment: cool! that works. Why did this work and the previous one didn't? Also, why not groups?

Comment: @Jay you can add groups as before....it is essentially same regex.....just wihout `s` flag

Comment: @vks how can I make sure that there is no overlap? For instance, everything works fine till `\n16\.(.+?)`, but once you introduce 17, the penultimate match will now eat into the last match. Try it out.

Comment: @Jay then make you regex this way.......this is failproof https://regex101.com/r/wL4aB6/2

Comment: @vks Where is the space? I don't see any space? the regex actually works till 3. `\n1\.(?:(?!\n\d+\.)[\s\S])*\n2\.(?:(?!\n\d+\.)[\s\S])*\n3\.` but fails from 4.